# Scala Aggregate result from multiple Future calls

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework, future

Consider a Model for Master/Slave election for a cluster.

```
Member{ id: Long, isMaster: Boolean }
```

I have a Dao/Repo with following methods:

```
MemberDao.findById(id:Long):Future[Option[Member]]
MemberDao.update(id:Long, member: Member):Future[Unit]
MemberDao.all() : Future[List[Member]]
```

Within the MemberService, I'm trying to write a function to set isMaster to false for all existing members, and I'm ending up with this crazily bloated code:

```
class MemberService ... {
  def demoteAllMembers() : Future[Boolean] = {
    val futures = memberDao.all.map{ memberFuture =>
      memberFuture.map{ member =>
        memberDao.findById(member.id).map { existingMemberFuture =>
          existingMemberFuture.map { existingMember =>
            memberDao.update(existingMember.id, existingMember.copy(isMaster = false)
          }
        }
      }
      val results = Await.result(futures, 10 seconds)

      // return something here
    }
  }


}
```

My Questions are: 
1. How should the return statement be written to handle success / errors? e.g. On success, return Future(true) and on failure, return Future(false)
2. Is this way of repetitively mapping future the correct way of doing async programming in scala? I understand this could be written differently in Actor paradigm and probably much better, but in case of OOP, is this the best Scala can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing MemberDao.findById when you are already holding a member in hand??? (You are also treating the return as a Member, while it should really be an Option[Member]). 
Also, update does not need to take an id as a separate parameter (there is one available inside `member`). 
You don't need to `Await` your result, because your function is returning a `Future`, and you don't need to return a `Boolean`: just throw an exception to signal failure.
Consider something like this:

```
def demoteAllMembers: Future[Unit] = memberDao.all.flatMap { 
   Future.sequence(_.foreach {
     memberDao.update(_.copy(isMaster = false))
   })
 }.map ( _ => () )
```

Not all that bloated, is it? :)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, obviously a novice scala developer here, one more question, memberDao.update takes in a Member, not a Future[Member], which is what memberDao.all will return. So I'm guessing I'll need to do the memberFuture => mapping still?

Comment: No, in your definition `.all` returns a `Future[List[Member]]`. The first `.flatMap` in my snippet looks inside the `Future`, then `foreach` iterates through the list of `Member`.  Note though, that I have updated the answer to fix the return type incompatibility: you need a `Future.sequence` inside the `.flatMap` to convert list of futures into future list, and then the `.map` in the end discards the list to make the result `Future[Unit]` rather than `Future[List[Unit]]`